# Boost spirit poor performance with Alternative parser

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I already asked question about this issue. But since there were no answers i'm asking again now with full compilable source code snippet.

This code snippet should be compiled with no std=c++11 option, because of some issues with boost::variant move semantic. Just 'g++ -Wall -pedantic'.

In this code snippet you will find "// Comment here" line. You can comment following block till "// And here -----". 
If this block is uncommented, performance of this program is very poor.

So the bottleneck as long as i can see is alternative parser. What i need is some suggestions on improving/changing my grammar to improve parse perfomance. Thanks.

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_object.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

namespace client {
  typedef std::string::iterator input_iterator_type;

  struct op_and {}; 
  struct op_or {};
  struct op_eq {};
  struct op_neq {};
  struct is_part_of {};
  struct more {};
  struct more_eq {};
  struct less {};
  struct less_eq {};
  struct mask_match {};
  struct mask_not_match {};
  struct in {};

 namespace type {
    enum code_t {
      string       = 0,
      boolean      = 1,
      number       = 2,
      none         = 3,
      datetime     = 4,
      unknown      = 5
    }; 
  }

  template <typename tag>  struct binop;
  struct   fn_call;
  struct   none_type {~none_type(){}};

  struct datetime {
    datetime(int yyyy, int mm, int dd, int hh24, int mi, int ss, int mls) 
      : yy(yyyy), mm(mm), dd(dd), hh(hh24), mi(mi), ss(ss), ms(mls) {}
    datetime()
      : yy(0), mm(0), dd(0), hh(0), mi(0), ss(0), ms(0) {}
    int yy; int mm; int dd;
    int hh; int mi; int ss;
    int ms;
  };

  typedef boost::variant<
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_eq> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_neq> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<is_part_of> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<more> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<more_eq> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<less> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<less_eq> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<mask_match> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<mask_not_match> >,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<in> >
  > generic_binop;

  typedef boost::variant <
    std::string, double, none_type, datetime,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<generic_binop>,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<fn_call>
  > node_value_t;

  struct g_node {
    mutable type::code_t type_id; 
    mutable node_value_t value;
  };

  typedef node_value_t value_type;

  template <typename tag> struct binop { 
    explicit binop(const g_node& l, const g_node& r) 
      : oper1(l), oper2(r) {}
    g_node oper1, oper2; 
  };

  typedef std::vector<g_node> node_vector;

  struct fn_call {
    explicit fn_call(){}
    std::string name;
    node_vector params;
  };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
client::g_node,
(client::type::code_t, type_id)
(client::node_value_t, value)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
client::fn_call,
(std::string, name)
(std::vector<client::g_node>, params)
)

namespace client {

  template <typename Iterator> struct g_error_handler {
   template<typename, typename, typename, typename> 
    struct result { typedef void type; };

    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last,
          Iterator err_pos, boost::spirit::info const& what) const { 
      std::cout << "Syntax error. Expected: " << what << " at: " << 
        std::distance(first, err_pos) << std::endl;
    }
};

  template<typename Iterator, typename ErrorHandler = g_error_handler<Iterator> >
  struct g_parser : qi::grammar<Iterator, g_node(), ascii::space_type> {
    g_parser() : g_parser::base_type(or_, "G"), error_handler(ErrorHandler()) {

      using phoenix::at_c;

      or_ = (and_ >> "||" >> or_)[
        at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
        at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<op_or> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        and_[qi::_val = qi::_1];

      and_ = (bool_op >> "&&" >> and_)[
        at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
        at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<op_and> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        bool_op[qi::_val = qi::_1];

      bool_op = 
        (prim >> "=" >> bool_op)[
        at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
        at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<op_eq> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> "<>" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<op_neq> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
          // Comment here ---------------------------------------------------
        (prim >> ":" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<is_part_of> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> ">" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<more> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> ">=" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<more_eq> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> "<" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<less> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> "<=" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<less_eq> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> "=~" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<mask_match> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> "!~" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<mask_not_match> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
        (prim >> "in" >> bool_op)[
          at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, 
          at_c<1>(qi::_val) = phoenix::construct<binop<in> >(qi::_1, qi::_2)] |
          // And here------------------------------------------------------------ 
        prim[qi::_val = qi::_1];

       prim = 
         string_val   [qi::_val =  qi::_1] |
         number       [qi::_val =  qi::_1] |
         func_call    [at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::unknown, at_c<1>(qi::_val) =  qi::_1] | 
         '(' > or_    [qi::_val =  qi::_1] > ')';

       quoted_string %= "'" > qi::lexeme[*(qi::char_ - "'")] > "'";

       func_call = fn_name > '(' > -(or_ % ',') > ')';
       fn_name %= +(qi::alpha) > -(qi::char_('-')) > *(qi::alnum);

       string_val = quoted_string[
         at_c<0>(qi::_val) = type::string, at_c<1>(qi::_val) = qi::_1];

       number %= qi::attr(type::number) >> qi::double_;

       or_.name           ("OR expression"  );
       and_.name          ("AND expression" );
       bool_op.name       ("BOOL expression");
       prim.name          ("Atom expression");
       quoted_string.name ("quoted string"  );
       fn_name.name       ("function name"  );
       number.name        ("number"         );

       qi::on_error<qi::fail>(or_, error_handler(qi::_1, qi::_2, qi::_3, qi::_4));
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, g_node(), ascii::space_type> 
      and_, bool_op, prim, or_, string_val, number;
    qi::rule<Iterator, fn_call(), ascii::space_type> func_call;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> quoted_string, fn_name;

    boost::phoenix::function<ErrorHandler> error_handler;
  };

  typedef g_parser<input_iterator_type> grammar;
}

int main() {
  std::string s = "((foo(bar('','')) = foo('')) || ('a' = 'gg')) && (3 <> 7) && (foo('','') = bar('','')) && 2=4 && 'a' ='b' && foo('') <> foo('')";
  client::grammar g;
  client::g_node ast;
  std::string::iterator begin = s.begin();
  std::string::iterator end = s.end();
  bool success = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, g, 
    boost::spirit::ascii::space, ast) && begin == end;
  std::stringstream ss;
  if(!success)
    std::cout << "Syntax error at: " << std::distance(s.begin(), begin);
  else std::cout << "Syntax is Ok\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refactor the grammar to induce less backtracking. I've done an example of such a refactoring before on SO.

<strike>Link: not found</strike>

However, here's the gist. The following should be equivalent, except for the vastly reduced need to backtrack:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/366af479dee7875d)**

```
using boost::phoenix::construct;
using qi::_val;
using qi::_1;

bool_op =
    prim [ _val = _1 ] >> -((
    ("="  >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<op_eq> >          (_val, _1) ]) |
    ("<>" >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<op_neq> >         (_val, _1) ]) |
    (":"  >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<is_part_of> >     (_val, _1) ]) |
    (">"  >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<more> >           (_val, _1) ]) |
    (">=" >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<more_eq> >        (_val, _1) ]) |
    ("<"  >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<less> >           (_val, _1) ]) |
    ("<=" >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<less_eq> >        (_val, _1) ]) |
    ("=~" >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<mask_match> >     (_val, _1) ]) |
    ("!~" >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<mask_not_match> > (_val, _1) ]) |
    ("in" >> bool_op [ at_c<1>(_val) = construct<binop<in> >             (_val, _1) ])
    ) >> qi::eps     [ at_c<0>(_val) = type::unknown ])
    ;
```

Also note my tendency to avoid repeated code, and *present the code*. Even if you have a coding standard that imposes a maximum line-length, it is **clearly** more legible, more maintainable and **much** less error prone to layout the code in aligned columns, like I did. In fact, you could just argue that this piece of code is "meta-data", a table if you will, and you can make a well-reasoned exception.

I think I see a number of other "code smells" - or, more positively, "opportunities for simplification".

I have in fact refactored many grammars just like these in the past on SO and usually reduced the code to <50% of the original code, often adding features at the same time. I sadly don't have time to find them right now, but maybe you can have a look for yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can point out main milestones? At least are there any improvements from the grammar only point of view? I mean i'll try different data structure especially for strings and so on, but maybe there is some evident change in the grammar itself?

Comment: @Alexander added, sadly I don't have more time at the moment. I hope this helps you get started. PS. See the modified grammar **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/366af479dee7875d)** (0.006s)

Comment: (Oh and yes, `string_ref` can help iff the source is a contiguous character array, but this kind of performance mishap is _always_ an algorithmic complexity problem. Reducing the number of allocations only reduces the constant factor, but O(e^n) will still be O(e^n), e.g.)

Comment: Wow! Your version runs at blazing speed. Thanks a lot! Could you spend one more minute of your time and explain why my version was so slow? My explanation is: first we parse (prim >> "=" >> bool_op), essentially we parse whole prim and then check next char, if we fail and go to the next alternative where we parse prim one more time and so on. Am i right?

Comment: @Alexander Yes. And what's more, `prim` might actually be a whole subtree, so the cost is compounded