# boost::fusion parsing long string causes stack overflow

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, grammar, boost-spirit

Is there any way how to prevent boost::fusion to overflow stack on certain input? I have grammar similar to

```
S -> S OR S
S -> a
```

and on huge input (>1500 OR'd items) it crashes. I don't want to parse such a huge input, but I need somehow to prevent process crashing.

I can probably limit the string to be of some length, but that doesn't solve my problem, as `a` may be long.

Comment: First, it's not fusion crashing, that's Spirit (or more specifically, your rules). Show your code (SSCCE) and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: It looks like you're parsing boolean expressions. Have you looked at [Boolean Expression grammar with Boost Spirit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706356/boolean-expression-grammar-parser-in-c/8707598#8707598) for ideas? There's a [followup that does evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598029/how-to-calculate-boolean-expression-in-spirit/12602418#12602418) too

Answer (score 1):

This is usually tackled by rewriting right-recursion into a form of iteration, e.g.

```
myrule = something >> -(',' >> myrule); // right recursion
```

into

```
myrule = something *(',' >> myrule); // iteration
```

Of course, this is a trivial case. In real grammars, you'd often need to somehow keep the operator precedence in check.

---

In the absense of code see here for examples of refactoring grammars to be ***much*** lighter on the stack and allocations:

- **[Syntax tree empty nodes issue with Spirit Qi MiniC example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707254/syntax-tree-empty-nodes-issue-with-spirit-qi-minic-example/19715064#19715064)** - which is exactly about this: deeply nested expressions
- **[Boost spirit poor perfomance with Alternative parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242408/boost-spirit-poor-perfomance-with-alternative-parser/23242863#23242863)**, which was a similar case
- Possibly related: [How to benchmark Boost Spirit Parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918831/how-to-benchmark-boost-spirit-parser/16931098#16931098)